# Unable to kill process with 'kill -9' whose PPID=1 and using 100% of CPU?

Tags: sudo, process, kill

**Direct Question:** Flash under firefox 4.0, npviewer.bin, in KUbuntu 10.04 was running at 100% and I couldn't kill it.  I tried:

```
sudo kill -9 12996
sudo kill -15 12996
```

I logged in as root and ran both commands.  The PPID was listed as 1.  (Can't kill init without rebooting).  I, as root, issued a `reboot` command and also a `shutdown now`.  I went through the list of running processes and manually killed every single process most became `<defunct>`.  The system has a RAID 5 without a battery backup -- so I don't like yanking the cord out of the UPS, but this is what I ended up having to do.

Is there something else I should've tried?  Some other command to run?  It was using 100% of the CPU, and I need to finish my dissertation, so I just forcibly turned off the computer, but if it happens again, I'd like to be prepared.  Note:  I also renice'd the process to 19 and it 'took' -- i.e. it responded that the process was now at nice 19 and was at nice 0.  However, it was still using 100% of the cpu.

**Background:** A friend was using the computer, so I haven't yet cycled through the history to see if there was anything malicious, but it crashed when he started firefox and it returned to ESPN's fantasy baseball website -- not a place I would expect flash malware to grow...  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the SysRq method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#.22Raising_Elephants.22_mnemonic_device

You want to run them in a certain order as described in the wiki article: R E I S U B